# Google spreadsheets HYPERLINK not working if another formula is used before it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im writing an easy google spreadsheet automation code and I ran into a problem with HYPERLINK function and its crutial since I have to add a link.
Basically what is happening is I have a cell with multiple functions that are seperated by "&" symbol and at the end of the cell I'm trying to add a HYPERLINK function but its not working because it requires a "=" symbol, but I cannot do that since i'm already using "&"
Example:
What works if used alone in cell: =HYPERLINK(url, name)
What I have in said cell and that doesn't work is: "some code" & HYPERLINK(url, name)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to make a part of a cell a link. You can wrap all the formulas with hyperlink formula to have all the data diplayed as link.
Or it will just display a label.

Take a look at this example:
[image]

The formula does not need = before it.

My advice is to put hyperlink formula in a separate cell to avoid problems. This is the only way to manage it (in my opinion).

Comment: Ye, thats what I thought, thanks for the answer, cheers.

Comment: Please mark my answer as useful (arrow up in the top left corner).